# Javascript. Building a string from checkbox values and filtering by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a series of checkboxes with the ID 'colour' and a text field with id 'result-colour'.

I have this script which will populate the text field with whatever is 'checked'. This works fine!

```
var arr = []
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
         arr.push($(this).val())
       }
    })
    var vals = arr.join(", ")
    var str = vals
  
    $('#result-text-colour').text(str);
```

But I also have other checkboxes on the same page (with different id's) but they also appear in the string

I tried to filter my code with:

```
var checkboxElementClicked = (this.id); 
//alert(checkboxElementClicked);
if (checkboxElementClicked == 'colour'){

var arr = []
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
         arr.push($(this).val())
       }
    })
    var vals = arr.join(", ")
    var str = vals
  
    $('#result-text-colour').text(str);
};
```

which appeared to work, until I click a 'colour checkbox' and then everything that was checked appears in the string...

Can anyone help me filter out everything else apart from colour id's to go into my string?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Tag jquery in your question next time. Never use duplicate IDs.

Comment: `$(":checkbox").each` will always get all of them (for unrelated inputs) - you need to find a way to only get the ones you're interested in.  The simplest way is to wrap each input+checkboxlist into a separate div and use that.  Without any HTML, it's a bit hard to advise specifics.  Something like `<div class='wrapper'><input type='textbox' class='result'><input type='checkbox'></div>` then `$(":checkbox").on("change", function() { $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(":checkbox") ... $(this).closest(".wrapper").find(".result").text(str) })`

Comment: Thanks freedomn-m, that did the trick! :)